# Tkinter lambda command is inable to call a whole script

Tags: python, tkinter

I had a script that looked like this:

```
add_game_btn = Button(top_menu,text="ADD GAME",command=add_game.create_game)
```

which seemed to work perfectly for me, executing the command when the button was pressed.

I soon moved the command to the whole another py file, so now the code looks like this:

```
import create_game
add_game_btn = Button(top_menu,text="ADD GAME",command=create_game)
```

*create_game* is another python script that I have in the same directory

The problem is when I run the script it automatically executes that script, even putting in `lambda` doesn't work.
Does anyone know how I could make this work?

Comment: `import create_game` will execute `create_game.py` in order to interpret its content.  You need to do the stuff in a function inside `create_game`, like your first example.

Comment: When you run `import module`, it executes the `module.py` file, by default(so that the name-spaces can merge). If you don't want that to happen, then put the code that is exclusive to appear only when running `create_game.py` inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block and use the function with the script: `command=create_game.func_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run an entire python file in that way, but you can create a function in the file that needs to be imported and then run that function like so:

Content of `create_game.py` (the file that needs to be executed on button click)

```py
def my_game_function():
    print("Game created!")
    # Do your things here
```

Content of `main.py`

```py
import tkinter as tk
import create_game

top_menu = tk.Tk()
add_game_btn = tk.Button(top_menu, text="ADD GAME", command=create_game.my_game_function)

add_game_btn.place(
    relx=0.5,
    rely=0.5,
    anchor="center"
)

top_menu.mainloop()
```

The function `my_game_function` will be executed on button click.